# not getting hidden values while postback of a button in.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am using asp.net.
I have taken one Hidden value and assigning value to that hidden variable in Java-script.

**aspx:**     `<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnProductionIds" value="0" name="hdnProductionIds" />`

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnProductionIds").value = "123";
```

I want to use that hidden value in server side coding(vb.net). But while do-post back, hidden variable value becomes Zero (default value)

Can any one please suggest me.

Thanks, Jagadi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the request form collection

```
Dim prodIDs as String= Request.Form("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnProductionIds")
```